# How do I create a shortcut that launches a non-default-browser to a website

Tags: windows, shortcuts, url, hyperlink

I want to be able to double click it and it runs the correct (non default) browser and opens my preferred website?

Comment: Why would you want to do this rather than create a bookmark?

Comment: I want this to sit on my desktop. I'm using windows 7 - so typically a url will open with IE, but I want to specify that it open with a diff browser, something you can't do with Windows7 built in url creator. This used to be done in WindowsXP and earlier also

Comment: Not such a strange nor bad question. I do this with a simple bat-file as I showed in my answer below. I use Firefox for everything *except* my banking that demands IE. So I have a `bank.bat` that launches IE and takes me to the correct site.

Answer (score 10):

1. Create a new shortcut (Right-click->New->Shortcut)
2. Point the shortcut to the executable of your browser of choice (e.g., "C:\Program Files\Mozilla\Firefox\firefox.exe")
3. Add the URL you wish to go to after the executable ("http://kongregate.com")
   [image: New shortcut creation screen]
4. Name the shortcut whatever you want.
5. Double-click the shortcut to open your webpage in the designated browser.

Comment: @VISQL - The answer clearly tells you how and when to select what browser you want to use for that particular url.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you create a simple `bat` file.

Put this in a textfile on your desktop and then rename it to `amazon-with-chrome.bat` or something.

```
start C:\Users\YOUR-WINDOWS-USER-NAME\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe http://www.amazon.com
```

It launches chrome.exe and loads amazon.com you. You need to replace *http://www.amazon.com* and *YOUR-WINDOWS-USER-NAME* at a minimum.
If you want to use another browser (or if you have chrome installed somewhere else) you have to change the path too.

**EDIT:**
If this dont work (perhaps you downt have permissions to execute random bat-files) her is an alternative

- Make a copy of the shortcut to your non-standard browser
- Right click shortcut and choose properties
- Find the `Target`-field on the `Shortcut` tab and just put the url you want to visit at the end of what's already there. Be sure to add a space before your addition

For me the value was
`"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --profile-directory="Profile 1"`

Just add your favourite website like this so
`"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --profile-directory="Profile 1" https://zombo.com/`
and save.

Remember to rename your shortcut

Comment: I like this! Never seen it done with batch file. This is exactly the functionality I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: This solution isn't working for me, is there an updated method?

Comment: @greenage Oh, this is an old question. I'm not surprised it doesent work anymore.  But as requested I have added an alternative

Comment: @Nifle - Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is to create a shortcut on your desktop (Right click > New > Shortcut) and point it at a website.

Comment: Thanks. That doesn't allow me to choose the browser though, such as with other user-created files. I don't want it to open with IE. However, that is the only option when creating a Windows shortcut in which a url is placed.

Answer (score 2):

If you insist on doing this with an HTML file, you could put this in your file:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0;url=http://www.example.com">
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

That will automatically redirect to the linked URL. Select the browser by right-clicking and selecting "Open with..." and picking the browser you want to use.

Comment: And how will this open in the correct browser?

Comment: @Nifle I have no idea. But he keeps insisting that this must be done with an HTML file. Your answer and my previous answer are both perfectly good ways to do this, but he seems opposed to anything not done in HTML.

Answer (score 1):

What I was looking for was something like this http://www.webworkshop.net/auto-redirecting_methods.html

Auto-redirect metatag.

By making it an html file, I can edit which browser it opens with

[image: Enter htmlcode into a TXT file]
[image: Click to change the .txt extension]

[image: Change the extentsion to html]

[image: Yes. It's ok.]

[image: File becomes an html file]

[image: Double-click open to the webpage you entered]

[image: You can choose what to open it with]

[image: You can change with browser it opens with by default. Hooray.]

Comment: Please crop your pictures.

Comment: lol. I'll shrink them next time, but context is good, no?

Answer (score -1):

This is rubbish,

start C:\Program Files (x86)\SRWare Iron\chrome.exe http://www.amazon.com

The above will not work in a Bat file.  Only the three main browsers can be opened in a batch file - none of the lesser known clones!

You can create a shortcut by entering the following into the "Type the location of the item":

"C:\Users\Joe Blogs\AppData\Local\Epic Privacy Browser\Application\epic.exe" http://google.com.au

Adapt it by entering your address to the browser you want and the site name.

Comment: If you formatted your command correctly it might stand a chance of working. `start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\SRWare Iron\chrome.exe" http://www.amazon.com`. You clearly don't know how to use [start](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html) properly.

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)